# Java get fields from raw type ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, field, raw-types

i have a problem with taking the x from an ArrayList in a for.
Let me explain better with this code:
    `private ArrayList pointStorer = new ArrayList();`

I first declare the ArrayList

```
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){

   for(int i = 0; i < pointStorer.size(); i++){
       if(pointStorer.get(i).x <= e.getX()){
           check = true;
       }
   }
}
```

Then when i try to pass the ArrayList and for every element get the x, it doesn't work, Java says that 'cannot find simbol' (the x).

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: @Reimeus is attempting to point you in the right direction. You need to tell the ArrayList what it composes of if you want to get access to the variables of what it is made of.

Comment: yes, but this didn't help... i still can't understandt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get an element from your `pointStorer` you need to cast it to `Point` (or whatever class you are using), otherwise the program will not know its type and it will not know it has an `x` field.

But it would be better to explicitly define the array type, like this:

```
private List<Point> pointStorer = new ArrayList<Point>();
```

this way when you use `get` it will directly return a `Point` object and you would not have to cast it to access its fields.

Answer (score 1):

Java think you have an `ArrayList` of `Object`.
You should give a type parameter like: `ArrayList<Point>` or other type with field `x`.